# Keep inside the cell, don't let it cover the neighboring cell

Tags: excel

Suppose I have 30 characters written in cell B4 (with 20.00), while C4 is a blank cell. I don't need to see the entire B4 text, but it still overwrites on C4, which is blank. How can I set the cell setting, so that only initial characters of B4 would be visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below screenshot if you have any doubt to understand @John Coleman's answer.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Under B4's cell format select the option `Fill` in `Alignment/Text Alignment/Horizontal`.